# IE8 sessionID incremented

Tags: session, asp-classic, internet-explorer-8, sessionid

I have the page written on classic ASP and href element on it. Href leads to the same page but with another query parameters.

After clicking the link all the session variables become clear.

With the Response.Write(session.sessionID) command I compare session ID before and after clicking the link. And I've found out that it was autoincremented.

It happens ONLY in IE8, other browsers work fine.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: is the href link a true href link or are you using javascript to change the location?

Comment: <a style="font-size: 13pt;" href="/admin/license.asp?checkOut=1&ppId=<%=Request.QueryString("ppId")%>">
smth like that

Answer (score 0):

If the new link is in a different virtual directory than the originating link, a new session will get created...

Comment: the page is the same, just query parameters values changed. By the way https is used there!! when I use http everything is fine.